# How do I Integrate YouTube V3 API into an iOS Project?

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I want to upload recorded videos to YouTube from my app. Some guides suggested that I use the YouTube V3 API SDK from Google. I downloaded it. How do I use it? I dragged all classes to my project and I'm getting ARC issues.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Google Sign-In SDK to version 2.4.0 fixed the ARC issues for me.

Google now recommends using Cocoapods to manage their SDK dependency, so a `pod install Google` or `pod update Google` worked for me.  If you're just using the Google Sign-In SDK, you can just use `pod install Google/SignIn`.

If you are not using Cocoapods, you can manually install the Sign-In SDK by downloading it from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/) and linking the binary with your project.